# iOS JSON Parsing to tableview, incorrect rows

Tags: mysql, ios, json, parsing

I am developing an iOS App, I have a tableview controller populated from a MySQL database. When I click on a raw a detailview appears showing data from the database, such as a master detail app. The problem is following:
1. When I run the app on the iPhone simulator, the app shows the three records from the mysql table, thats correct.
2. If I click on the first row, nothing happened.
3. If I click on the second or third row, the app opens the detailview, but the data don't correspond to the selected row(record).
4. I click on the back button of the detailview, and the app opens the masterview again.
5. Now if I click on the first row, the app opens the detailview, but as mentioned before, the detailview data don't correspond to the selected row(record) on the master view.
Here you have my viewcontroller code (master view):

```
    //
    //  ViewController.m

   //

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Areas";
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    [data appendData:theData];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;
    news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
    [mainTableView reloadData];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The download could not complete - please make sure you're connect to either 3G or WiFi" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorView show];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;

}

-(int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
-(int)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [news count];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    if(cell==nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
                }
    cell.textLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
      cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"nombre"];
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.title =[[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"nombre"];
    detailViewController.newsArticle = [news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

And here the detailview code:

```
//
//  DetailViewController.m

//

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize newsArticle;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    titleLabel.text = [newsArticle objectForKey:@"nombre"];
    timeLabel.text = [newsArticle objectForKey:@"name"];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Any idea what I have done wrong??
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.title =[[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"nombre"];
    detailViewController.newsArticle = [news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

You are using **didDeselectRow** which is called when a row is deselected and hence the wierd behaviour plus wrong data.. you have to use `didSelectRow`

Comment: Thank you Dante, I have been looking for the reason for a very long day. That's right.